# How to return the contents of an Rc?

Tags: rust

I am trying to return a moved value from an `Rc`:

```
if let Some(last_elem) = self.tail.take() {
    let last = Rc::clone(&last_elem);
    let tmp_node = last.borrow();
    let tmp = tmp_node.deref();
    return Some(*tmp);
}
```

Where:

- `self.tail` has type `Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>`;
- after borrow the `tmp_node` has type `Ref<Node<T>>`; and
- I would like to return `Option<Node<T>>`.

However the compiler complains, "cannot move out of `*tmp` which is behind a shared reference".

How can I fix this?

Comment: *"cannot move out of *tmp which is behind a shared reference"* should be clear. You don't own the value, you can't return it. You may clone it if you want.

Comment: Unlike in Python or Java, Rust values aren't implicitly heap-allocated. In order to return a value stored somewhere, you need to either move it from that location (and leave something else there), or clone it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I try clone change the like return Some(*(tmp.clone())); it is still complain about "cannot move out of a shared reference"

Comment: @EnXie, could you provide a [mre]? I have a possible answer to the problem you're having with `clone()`, but can't test it myself since the code given isn't sufficient to reproduce the situation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you very much, I give up on move data from Rc. Instead I create a new Obj for return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, it's impossible to move a value out of `Rc`, since it might be read concurrently from somewhere else.

However, if your code's logic can guarantee that this `Rc` is the sole owner of the underlying data, there's an escape hatch - [`Rc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap), which performs the check at runtime and fails if the condition is not fulfilled. After that, we can easily unwrap the `RefCell` (not `Ref`!) with [`RefCell::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.into_inner):

```
pub fn unwrap<T>(last_elem: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> T {
    let inner: RefCell<T> = Rc::try_unwrap(last_elem)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("The last_elem was shared, failed to unwrap"));
    inner.into_inner()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9eaca91382c87e1e5abd780b2d3038fb)

---

Another possible approach, if you want not to move value from `Rc` but to get a copy, would be to go with your original approach, but use `clone` instead of `deref`:

```
pub fn clone_out<T: Clone>(last_elem: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> T {
    last_elem.borrow().clone()
}
```

---

A side note: looks like you're trying to implement some kind of linked list. This is a notoriously hard problem to do in Rust, since it plays very bad with the single-ownership semantics. But if you're really sure you want to go though all the dirty details, [this book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) is highly recommended.

Comment: is that possible to clone it and move the variable as return ?

Comment: Of course, see the edit.

Comment: Why `unwrap_or_else(|| panic!())` instead of just `expect()`?

Comment: Good catch, thank you! Can't remember why I decided this way, so edited.

Comment: Enlightening. Your link introduces me to Playground for the first time. But this doesn't seem to build ("`T` doesn't implement `Debug`")... is this intended? Also it would no doubt be more useful to have an example which *does* something (trivial), particularly in a `RefCell` context, where things can mess up at runtime.

Comment: ...aha, thank you, missed that - that seems to be the reason for not using `expect` at the first place (so rolled back the previously mentioned change). As for the "example which does something" - do you mean runnable example, with `main`?