# "Unwrapping" Rc<RefCell<T>> in the proper way

Tags: rust, interior-mutability

I have a Rust data structure that I will have to pass around and manipulate from various places in my code. To my understanding the most simple and default way to do this is to wrap everything in `Rc` for the reference counting and a `RefCell` for interior mutability. I at least think that I have basic understanding of both structs and came up with the following approach:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

//  Some central data structure I would have to pass around and would like to manipulate from
//  different locations in my code.
struct MyState {
    data: i32 //  Some data
}

//  Just an example method that will mutate my sample state.
impl MyState {
    fn modify_state(&mut self, data: i32) {
        self.data += data;
    }
}

//  To be able to pass the structure around, I put it in a RefCell for interior mutability and Rc
//  for the ref counting. For convenience I wrap everything in a new type.
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStateRef(Rc<RefCell<MyState>>);

impl MyStateRef {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyStateRef(Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyState{data: 0})))
    }
}

fn main() {
    //  Create an instance of MyState wrapped in Rc and RefCell
    let state = MyStateRef::new();

    //  "state" could now be cloned and passed around. At some point I would like to modify the
    //  internal MyState by calling modify_state.
    state.0 [...???...] .modify_state(3);
}
```

I'm not able to make the last line in the `main` function work. I tried various combinations of `borrow_mut`, `get_mut`, ... but just failed. I think that there is some `Deref` and `DerefMut` involved that is confusing me, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Can somebody make the the last line work and explain why it is working?

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404603/how-to-return-the-contents-of-an-rc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) is your friend:

```
    state.0.borrow_mut().modify_state(3);
```