# Rust, how to copy the inner value out from Rc<RefCell<T>> and return it?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, refcell

**Brief**: I'm new to Rust so I decided to practice by implementing a double linked list. For debugging purpose, I implemented the `get()` method, but I failed to copy the value out from a `Rc<RefCell<_>>`. (Sorry for asking dumb question)

**Problem**: I'm trying to return a `Result<T, &'static str>` in `.get()` where the `T` is the type of the data stored in node and `&str` is the error message string. The borrow checker tells me that I cannot return a reference to an in-method variable, so I tried to copy the inner value out and return it, but failed to do so.

**Source code**:

```rust
use std::{rc::Rc, cell::RefCell};

struct Node<T> {
    data: Option<T>,
    prev: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    /// Instantiate a new dummy node.
    /// This node is used to mark the start and end of the list.
    /// It is not counted in the size of the list.
    fn new() -> Self {
        Node {
            data: None,
            prev: None,
            next: None,
        }
    }
    /// Instantiate a new content node.
    /// This node is used to store data.
    /// It is counted in the size of the list.
    fn from(data: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            data: Some(data),
            prev: None,
            next: None,
        }
    }
}

struct List<T> {
    head: Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>,
    tail: Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>,
    size: usize,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let head = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new()));
        let tail = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new()));
        head.borrow_mut().next = Some(Rc::clone(&tail));
        tail.borrow_mut().prev = Some(Rc::clone(&head));
        List { head, tail, size: 0 }
    }
    pub fn prepend(&self, data: T) {
        let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::from(data)));
        let mut head = self.head.borrow_mut();
        
        node.borrow_mut().next = Some(head.next.take().unwrap());
        node.borrow_mut().prev = Some(Rc::clone(&self.head));
        head.next = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
        if let Some(next) = node.borrow().next.as_ref() {
            next.borrow_mut().prev = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
        };
    }
    pub fn append(&self, data: T) {
        let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::from(data)));
        let mut tail = self.tail.borrow_mut();
        
        node.borrow_mut().prev = Some(Rc::clone(&tail.prev.take().unwrap()));
        node.borrow_mut().next = Some(Rc::clone(&self.tail));
        tail.prev = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
        if let Some(prev) = node.borrow().prev.as_ref() {
            prev.borrow_mut().next = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
        };
    }
    pub fn get(&self, index: isize) -> Result<T, &'static str> {
        let mut current: Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>> = Rc::clone(self.head.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap());
        for _ in 0..index {
            let tmp = Rc::clone(current.borrow().next.as_ref().ok_or("Index out of range")?);
            current = tmp;
        }
        let result = current.borrow().data.as_ref().ok_or("Index out of range")?;  // error[E0716]
        Ok(*result)  // error[E0507]
    }
}
/*
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src\linked.rs:74:22
   |
74 |         let result = current.borrow().data.as_ref().ok_or("Index out of range")?;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                      |
   |                      creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
75 |         Ok(*result)
   |            ------- borrow later used here
   |
help: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
   |
74 ~         let binding = current.borrow();
75 ~         let result = binding.data.as_ref().ok_or("Index out of range")?;
   |

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*result` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\linked.rs:75:12
   |
75 |         Ok(*result)
   |            ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*result` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
*/
```

**I've Tried**:

- [This post about making a reference into value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function), but that's what I'm trying to do and failed.
- [This post about modifying a `RefCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188506/unwrapping-rcrefcellt-in-the-proper-way), but this did not help. I was trying to return it, not mutate it.
- [This post about how to borrow a `RefCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349577/how-to-borrow-the-t-from-a-refcellt-as-a-reference), but I can't return the borrowed value because the borrowed `Rc` is short lived (but the inner value is not).
- [This post about how to return something inside a `RefCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap) and [this post about how to return it with `.map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281664/how-do-i-borrow-a-refcellhashmap-find-a-key-and-return-a-reference-to-the-re), but I the compiler says "trait bound not satisfied" when I tried to use `.into()` and borrow checker complains "cannot move out" if I remove the `.into()`.
- [This post about using `Rc::try_unwarp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404603/how-to-return-the-contents-of-an-rc), but it won't work since the inner data has more than one owner.

**Also**: I may did these wrong, please forgive me if one of the posts solved my problem but I did not implement it in the right way, and please teach me how to do it properly. Many thanks.

Comment: "I'm new to Rust so I decided to practice by implementing a double linked list" Stop here. This is a bad idea. Don't practice Rust by implementing a linked list, doubly so for a  double linked list. This won't teach you idiomatic or good Rust, this will just confuse you.

Comment: read this https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: And if you must, or _after_ you already mastered Rust and you want to challenge (yes, challenge! This is a hard one) yourself with building this data structure, make sure to read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: Still, this is a good post and worth an upvote, because you did your research. Good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    pub fn get(&self, index: isize) -> Result<T, &'static str>
        where T: Clone
    {
        let mut current: Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>> = Rc::clone(self.head.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap());
        for _ in 0..index {
            let tmp = Rc::clone(current.borrow().next.as_ref().ok_or("Index out of range")?);
            current = tmp;
        }
        let guard = current.borrow();
        guard.data.clone().ok_or("Index out of range")
    }
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=897c198962676e682076a4f31afc8933))

You need the line `where T: Clone` to enable the `.clone()` method.

---

Some say it's a mistake to implement a doubly-linked list in order to learn Rust... I'm sorry to report that they are right. I did the exact same thing when I started. The other thing I tried was writing a ray-tracer; that went a lot better.

Core data structures are implemented using raw pointers. That means writing unsafe code and putting a safe API around it: an advanced Rust skill.

Answer (score 4):

You don't.

If the value is `Copy`, you can copy it. If it is `Clone`, you can clone it. But if it is not, or it is too expensive to clone?

You're out of luck.

Interior mutability (like `RefCell`) is bad for APIs. It tend to propagate across API boundaries, and sometimes even stops you altogether from implementing them. It is good (sometimes) *inside* the implementation, but not as it leaks.

Of course, there is a proper way to implement a doubly linked list (since [std has one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html)), but this proper way requires unsafe code. You may want to return to it when you've already mastered Rust, as an exercise. And make sure to read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html).